# C# Padding Amount With Zeros

Tags: c#, decimal, zero, zero-pad

I have an `amount` field which is a decimal in the database.
I need to always display this amount with 10 numbers on the left of the decimal and two after.

Example:
`Amount = 245.00` which should display as `0000000245.00`
Additionally, the amount could be over 1,000 or 10,000 which should display as:

`0000001245.00` and `0000011245.00`

How can I format the amount to always have the appropriate number of zeros on the left side of the decimal with a variable amount size?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should put 0's in your format string.  Something like this.

```
myValue.ToString("0000000000.00");
```

That will always give you 10 digits on the left side of your decimal point and two on the right.

If you do not want two digits on the right side... do this.

```
myValue.ToString("0000000000.##");
```

This says hey if we have a value display it; otherwise, skip it.

Comment: This will do the rounding.

Answer (score 10):

This should help... http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/

So you can use this

`string.Format("{0:0000000000.00}", 15.25); // "0000000015.25"`

Comment: I thought this, too, but re-read the question. The digits to the right of the decimal point should vary and not always be exactly two.

Comment: @Yuck That's not how I understand it `I need to always display this amount with 10 numbers on the left of the decimal and two after.`... it will not work with numbers bigger than 9999999999 though, because then he'll has 11 numbers in front :)

Comment: Note that ToString is more efficient than string.Format.  In other words, assuming `d` is a decimal variable, `d.ToString("0000000000.00")` is more efficient than `string.Format("{0:0000000000.00}", d)`

Comment: Still, if he doesn't need the two on the right he just swaps that format out. This is a viable answer depending on what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

yourDecimalVariable.ToString("0000000000.00") should do the trick.