# Left-pad a floating point number without losing trailing zeros after decimal point

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, fixed-width

I am attempting to write out to a fixed format text file and am having some trouble formatting the numbers properly. It needs to be padded with leading zeros and an implied decimal.

Example:

```
43.80
```

The output would need to be:

```
0000004380
```

So far, I have attempted to convert the double to a string, replace the decimal, and then pad with "0".

```
((amount.ToString()).Replace(".","")).PadLeft(10, '0')
```

The problem with this is when the number ends with zeros. The above example comes out as:

```
0000000438
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Decimal.Truncate(amount * 100m).ToString("0").PadLeft(10, '0')` would do it, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Padding Amount With Zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587819/c-sharp-padding-amount-with-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decimal value = 34.80M;
int intVal = (int)(value * 100);
return intVal.ToString("0000000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
((string.Format("{0:0.00}", amount)).Replace(".","")).PadLeft(10, '0')
```

That way you don't lose the 2nd decimal place when the value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a .ToString() format string in as described in this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Does the incoming value always have two decimal places?  If so, you could multiply by 100 to get rid of the decimal, and then to .ToString("D10")

(Int)(43.80 * 100).ToString("D10")

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job : `$"{(int)(amount * 100):D010}"`